# third nearest element pl/sql oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I want to write a PL/SQL function, for below schema:

```
Parts (pid:integer, pname:string, year:integer, price:integer)
Suppliers (sid:integer, sname: string, state:string, zipcode:string)
Orders (pid:integer, sid:integer, quantity:integer)
```

The function must do this:

The PL/SQL function that takes a price as argument and returns the pid of the part that has the third-nearest price to the one given. Note that nearest can be either higher or lower. In case there are multiple parts with that property, choose the one with higher year. If there is still a tie, choose the one with highest pid.

I've don this so far, but I don't know how to detect the tie situation and process it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getThirdNearestPriceOfPart(price IN INTEGER)
RETURN Parts.pid%type
IS
    third_pid Parts.pid%type;

BEGIN
    SELECT P1.pid INTO third_pid

    FROM Parts P1

    WHERE (2) = (

            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Parts P2

            WHERE P2.price > P1.price OR P2.price < P1.price);

    RETURN third_pid;

  EXCEPTION

    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

            RETURN -1;
  END;
```

Please help me

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework problem.  You should edit your question and add any attempts that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The PL/SQL function that takes a price as argument and returns the pid of the part that has the third-nearest price to the one given.

I let up to you the *"write a PL/SQL function"* part -- but here are some guidances to write your SQL query:

- First, it is rather easy to calculate the *distance* between a given price an the price of each part: `ABS(price - reference_price)`
- given that, you can now order by that distance, then by year, then by pid using an `ORDER BY`  clause
- then you can number rows (using `ROWNUM`)
- finally keep only the third row. Ties have been processed as part of the previous `ORDER BY`  clause.

Something *like* that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROWNUM RN, V.* FROM (
    SELECT pid, ABS(price - 17.50) distance, price
    FROM Parts
    ORDER BY 2 asc, year desc, pid desc
    ) V
  ) V2
WHERE RN = 3
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/913b5/15